# Help finding all elements of order 2 in $S_6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, permutations

I am trying to find all elements of order 2 in $S_6$. I am trying to understand how to achieve this. Here is my attempt.
We need only count the number of permutation of the forms

$
(a_1 a_2)\\
(a_1a_2)(a_3a_4)\\
(a_1a_2)(a_3a_4)(a_5a_6)\\
$

In the first case we see there are $6 * 5$ pairs, but we are counting each pair twice because $(12)=(21)$. Thus we divide it by $2$ getting, $15$.

In the second case we have, in a similar fashion
$$
\frac{6*5}{2} *  \frac{4*3}{2}
$$
but since disjoint cycles commute, we are counting permutation of the form $(12)(34)$ and $(34)(12)$ as distinct when they are not, so  we divide by 2 again getting:

$$
\frac{6*5*4*3}{2*2*2} = 45.
$$

For the 3rd case we get 
$$
\frac{6*5}{2} *  \frac{4*3}{2} * \frac{2*1}{2}
$$

but since we now have 3 cycles which commute we must divide by $3$ getting.

$$
\frac{6*5 *4*3*2*1}{2*2*2*3} = 6*5 = 30.
$$

Adding up all these permutation yields  $ 15 + 45 + 30 = 90$. However, this is an odd numbered problem in my textbook, and the answer is given as $75$. I have looked over my calculation about 3 times now, where is my mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only possibilities are transpositions, products of two disjoint transpositions and products of three disjoint transpositions.

You've already counted the first two types correctly.

For products of three disjoint transpositions, there are ${6\choose 2} {4\choose 2}{2\choose 2}$ ordered sequences of such transpositions, but since they commute there are six different ways to arrange each trio (but those six ways are all the same element of $S_6$). Dividing by 6, you get the value 15 (rather than 30).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is with your 3rd case. You have to divide by $3!$, not $3$.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a small program done in GAP environment for finding the elements which other answers noted the main theoretical points about them.

```
gap> G:=SymmetricGroup(6);;
gap> e:=Elements(G);;
gap> f:=Filtered(e,t->Order(t)=2);

[ (5,6), (4,5), (4,6), (3,4), (3,4)(5,6), (3,5), (3,5)(4,6), (3,6), 
(3,6)(4,5), (2,3), (2,3)(5,6), (2,3)(4,5), (2,3)(4,6), (2,4), (2,4)(5,6), 
(2,4)(3,5), (2,4)(3,6), (2,5), (2,5)(4,6), (2,5)(3,4), (2,5)(3,6), (2,6), 
(2,6)(4,5), (2,6)(3,4), (2,6)(3,5), (1,2), (1,2)(5,6), (1,2)(4,5), 
(1,2)(4,6), (1,2)(3,4), (1,2)(3,4)(5,6), (1,2)(3,5), (1,2)(3,5)(4,6), 
(1,2)(3,6), (1,2)(3,6)(4,5), (1,3), (1,3)(5,6), (1,3)(4,5), (1,3)(4,6), 
(1,3)(2,4), (1,3)(2,4)(5,6), (1,3)(2,5), (1,3)(2,5)(4,6), (1,3)(2,6), 
(1,3)(2,6)(4,5), (1,4), (1,4)(5,6), (1,4)(3,5), (1,4)(3,6), (1,4)(2,3), 
(1,4)(2,3)(5,6), (1,4)(2,5), (1,4)(2,5)(3,6), (1,4)(2,6), (1,4)(2,6)(3,5), 
(1,5), (1,5)(4,6), (1,5)(3,4), (1,5)(3,6), (1,5)(2,3), (1,5)(2,3)(4,6), 
(1,5)(2,4), (1,5)(2,4)(3,6), (1,5)(2,6), (1,5)(2,6)(3,4), (1,6), 
(1,6)(4,5), (1,6)(3,4), (1,6)(3,5), (1,6)(2,3), (1,6)(2,3)(4,5), 
(1,6)(2,4), (1,6)(2,4)(3,5), (1,6)(2,5), (1,6)(2,5)(3,4) ]

gap> Size(f);
                                      75
```

Comment: GAP - our friend! +1