# How many elements of order 4 does $S_6$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

I am trying to count the number of elements of order 4 in $S_6,$ but my answer is not matching the one in the back of the book.

Here's my attempt:

Such elements are either of the form $(6543)(21)$ or $(6543).$  For the first type, we have $6!/(4\cdot2\cdot2)$ possibilities, where the second divisor $2$ arises because we must take into account the fact that $(6543)(21)=(21)(6543).$  For the second type, we have $6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3/4$ possibilities.

Adding these up, we obtain 45 + 90 = 135 elements of order$ $4.  But the back of the book says there are 180 such elements.  Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Don't forget that $(6543)$ and $(3654)$ are the same

Comment: @gregkow ...I didn't?

Comment: Oh, I see, I misinterpreted how I read your expressions, let me rethink this again.

Comment: There is exactly one of the first type for every one of the second type.  Your calculation for the second type is correct.  You don't need to divide the first type by 2.

Comment: @Michael Why not?  Isn't that what was done here?:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366499/help-finding-all-elements-of-order-2-in-s-6?rq=1

Comment: Ah, I think I have it. You don't need to divide by two the second time. First, you arrange the 6 elements in a string. We will *always* interpret the first 4 as a cycle and the second 2 as a cycle. Thus, we only need to divide by 4 and 2 once. The second 2 is unnecessary, as we never even counted $(21)(6543)$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: If it makes it clearer, there is a nice bijection from the first type to second, by noting that for each, the 4 cycle defines it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why in the other question dividing by 2 was necessary (and then by 3!, at the end) but it isn't necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Pick $4$ elements to form a cycle.

There are $3!$ cyclic orders in which to list them.

Then chose either a $2$-cycle or two $1$-cycles for the two remaining elements.

$$
\binom 6 4 \cdot 3!\cdot2 = 180.
$$

You were mistaken in dividing by $2$ to allow for commutativity of disjoint cycles.  You weren't counting them in those two different orders separately, so there's no occasion to divide by $2$.

Comment: Though I see your point, I still don't see why division was necessary on the other SE page but not here... the problems seem very similar to me. *What's different?*

Comment: Let me consider a different case.  What about the number of members of $S_4$ of the form $(12)(34).$  At a glance, there are three possibilities: "1 goes with 2", "1 goes with 3", "1 goes with 4" (i.e. $(12),(13),(14).)$  Concurrently, $((4\cdot3/2)\cdot(2\cdot1/2))/2 = 3.$  If we hadn't divided by two at the end, the answer would have been wrong.  How is this example different from the one in my original question?  Why don't we divide by two there, but clearly must here?

Comment: Which other SE page??