# How many elements of order 4 does $S_8$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Since the answers on questions asked by others weren't conclusive for me, I figured I'd ask myself.

We're obviously looking at $(a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4)$, $(a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4)(a_5 a_6)$, $(a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4)(a_5 a_6 a_7 a_8)$ and $(a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4)(a_5 a_6)(a_7 a_8)$.

For the first type we have $\frac{6*5*4*3}{4}$ possibilities.

But I struggle with finding the number of elements of the second and third type. That's also where the answers of the other questions are really confusing.

Should I divide by 2 for the second and third type because I don't need to make a distinction between $(a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4)(a_5 a_6)$ and $(a_5 a_6)(a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4)$? If I do, the number of elements of the second type would be $\frac{6!}{4*2*2}$.

On this page the answer is yes you do need to divide for commutativity:
[Help finding all elements of order 2 in $S_6$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366499/help-finding-all-elements-of-order-2-in-s-6?lq=1)

But on this page the answer is no:
[How many elements of order 4 does $S_6$ have?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863806/how-many-elements-of-order-4-does-s-6-have)

Comment: 1. There are also elements of the form $(a\ b\ c\ d)(e\ f)(g\ h)$. 2. You could try calculating the answer for $S_4$, $S_5$, and $S_6$, then look the numbers up in the Online Encyclopedia of Integers Sequences.

Answer (score 0):

For order $4$ in $S_8$ the cycle types will be $(4,4), (4,1,1,1,1), (4,2,1,1)$ and $(4,2,2)$.

My method of counting is to first consider all possible permutations of the $8$ elements and then start factoring out the repeats.

Suppose we want to count the number of elements of the cycle type $(4,2,2)$, then

1. The number of ways to permute all the $8$ elements with no conditions = $8!$.
2. For every permutation (say for example) $a,b,c,d,f,h,e,g$, you can gather them as $(a,b,c,d) , (f,h) , (e,g)$ to create an element of $S_8$ of cycle type $(4,2,2)$. But we will have some overcounting because of the following 
   \begin{align*}
   1). \quad  \color{blue}{(a \,b \,c \,d)}  (f \,h)  (e \,g) & = \color{red}{(d \,a \,b \,c)}  (f \,h)  (e \,g)\\
   2). \quad  (a \,b \,c \,d)  \color{blue}{(f \,h)}  (e \,g) & = (a \,b \,c \,d)  \color{red}{(h \,f)}  (e \,g)\\
   3). \quad  (a \,b \,c \,d)  (f \,h)  \color{blue}{(e \,g)} & = (a \,b \,c \,d)  (f \,h)  \color{red}{(g \,e)}\\
   4). \quad  (a \,b \,c \,d)  \color{blue}{(f \,h)  (e \,g)} & = (a \,b \,c \,d) \color{red}{(e \,g)  (f \,h)}
   \end{align*}

For 1). every cyclical shift of the  $4-$cycle will give the same element of $S_8$, so to compensate for that we need to divide by $4$.

For 2). every cyclical shift of the  $2-$cycle will give the same element of $S_8$, so to compensate for that we need to divide by $2$.

For 3). every cyclical shift of the  $2-$cycle will give the same element of $S_8$, so to compensate for that we need to divide by $2$.

For 4). every rearrangement of the two $2-$cycles will give the same element of $S_8$, so to compensate for that we need to divide by $2!$.

Thus number of **distinct **elements of $S_8$ with cycle type $(4,2,2)$ are
$$\frac{8!}{4 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2!}.$$

Likewise the number of elements of cycle type $(4,4)$ are
$$\frac{8!}{4 \cdot 4 \cdot 2!}.$$